# Differences between touchmove and mousemove

Tags: javascript, html, css, mousemove, touchmove

I have noticed that mousemove event when I move very fast the mouse is triggered few times and not every pixel I have moved my mouse.This reflects on animations because for this problem they don't seem fluid.Does ontouchmove have the same problem?

Comment: Test it out and see for yourself.

Comment: Oh,great answare.Thanks.If I could I had done yet.I don't understand...bha...

Answer (score 2):

Mousemove triggers everytime you hover over an new element. Touchmove triggers every touch but you may be not over an actual element.

Comment: If i want on actual element what i can do . My question here  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58934867/touch-move-working-diffrently-than-mousemove